# How set variable to same cell range across Worksheets and place a same value?

Tags: excel, vba, range

My `workbook` contain 2 almost identical `sheets`. I try to `set` object variable to both sheets range...

For first sheet:

```
Dim myData as String: myData = "test"
Dim rng as Range: Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C5")
rng.Value = myData
```

I have a larger number of `cells` set up in this way on the first sheet and I want to extend them to sheet2.

For both sheets (dont know how):

```
Dim myData as String: myData = "test"
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C5") + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C5")
rng.Value = myData
```

I need to put the same value in the same place on different sheets. Is it possible to simplify it somehow, or does it have to refer to each one separately "manually"?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop perhaps:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   ws.Range("C5").Value = myData
Next
```